# django alternative EMAIL_HOST settings

Tags: django, smtp, sendmail

I want to implement django managment command which send emails by smtp with not default settings from settings.py file such as:

```
EMAIL_HOST
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
FROM_MAIL 
EMAIL_USE_TLS
```

i want to send with my alternative settings different from settings.py without change it email settings for all site.

how to implement this?

Answer (score 5):

Define your alternate email settings and then create a new mail connection using those settings:

settings.py

```
ALTERNATE_EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your password'
ALTERNATE_EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your user'
ALTERNATE_EMAIL_HOST = ''
ALTERNATE_EMAIL_PORT = 123
ALTERNATE_EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Then create new connection using those settings:

```
from django.core import mail
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

# create new connection
connection = mail.get_connection()
connection.password = settings.ALTERNATE_EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
connection.username = settings.ALTERNATE_EMAIL_HOST_USER
connection.host = settings.ALTERNATE_EMAIL_HOST
connection.port = settings.ALTERNATE_EMAIL_PORT
connection.use_tls = settings.ALTERNATE_EMAIL_USE_TLS

# send email using new connection you just created
send_mail('my subject', 'my message', settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
         ['abc@gmail.com'], connection=connection)
```

Comment: EMAIL_HOST does not present here

Comment: Yup because you specifically said you don't want to use the default email settings. You need to add alternate email settings so that you can use it later. I have updated my answer.